# Differentiability of $f(x) = \exp(-1/x^2), f(0) = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = \exp(-1/x^2)$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. I'm trying to show that $f$ is differentiable with continuous derivative in all points $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, if $x\neq 0$ then $f(x) = \exp \circ g(x)$ being $g(x)=-1/x^2$. In that case, the chain rule can be used to see that $f$ is differentiable with derivative

$$f'(x) = \exp(g(x))g'(x) =\exp \left(\dfrac{-1}{x^2}\right)\dfrac{2}{x^3},$$

which clearly is continuous, since $\exp$ is continuous, $g$ is continuous and $g'$ is continuous on these points.

Now, when $x=0$ I don't really know what to do. By the definition I think it is not a good way, since we have

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\exp\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)}{x}$$

and I'm unsure on how to proceed. Of course I could write $\exp$ as a series, but I don't know how to rigorously justify the manipulations that follows.

So how to show that this function is differentiable with continuous derivative?

**EDIT:** As pointed out in comments, if we set $h(t)=te^{-t^2}$ and $q(x)=\exp\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)/x$ then if $s(x)=1/x$ we have

$$q(x)=h(s(x)).$$

Then it is intuitively clear that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}q(x)=\lim_{t\to \infty}h(t).$$

Now how to prove this rigorously? This change of variables involves one limit at infinity, and I'm unsure how to justify this.

Comment: *Hint:* One side of the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\exp\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)}{x}$

is given by $$\lim_{t\to\infty} te^{-t^2}$$

Can you find that?

Comment: @uniquesolution Could you clarify your note?

Comment: Thanks @SimonS! I've added one edit just regarding how to justify this change of variables rigorously. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your new question, if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$0 < x < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$

then

$$ 1/x > 1/\delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L | < \epsilon$$ and

$$t > 1/\delta \Rightarrow |f(1/t) - L| < \epsilon$$

The converse is also true.

That is, $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = L \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(1/x) = L$$

Similarly,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = L \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(1/x) = L$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(1/x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(1/x) = L$$

---

As for $\lim_{t\to\infty} te^{-t^2} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t}{e^{t^2}}$, apply l'Hopital's rule, this limit is equal to $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{2te^{t^2}} = 0$.

Similarly, $\lim_{t\to\color{magenta}{-}\infty} te^{-t^2} = 0$ and therefore the  derivative at $x = 0$ is zero:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - 0}{x - 0} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} = 0$$

---

You should now be able to show that the $n$-th derivative at $x = 0$ is zero for all $n \geq 1$.