# basic analysis: showing $e^{-1/x^2}$ is continuous at $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$

from definition I need to show $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = f(0)$$ I used the substitution $x = 1/t$ to show that the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} e^{-1/x^2} = 0$$ but what is $f(0)$ and how do I know that $0 = f(0)$

Comment: The function $f$ as written is not even defined at $x = 0$. But it can be extended to a continuous function at zero by defining $f(0) = 0$

Comment: @SimonS clears it up thanks.

Comment: I just don't understand why we say that "show $f$ is continuous at $0$" if as you said it is not defined at $0$. Are we essentially creating a new functionw here $f(0) = 0$. this means that the original $f$ is not continuous at 0 surely?

Comment: Yes, as written, the function cannot be continuous as $x = 0$ as zero is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: then this question makes no sense as it asks me to show that $f(x)$ is an infinitely differentiable function

Comment: Assume then that $f(0) = 0$ and do the rest of the work. Btw, the question of infinite differentiability of such an $f$ has been asked here several times, including in the last week. Search, if needed.

Comment: I have my own proof but how do I search for something as specific as this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510275/differentiability-of-fx-exp-1-x2-f0-0

Answer (score 2):

As was noted above, your original function $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$ is not defined at $x=0$. However, if and only if the limit of your function exists at the point where it isn't defined, then you can extend your function by considering the value of the limit as the value of your function at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a prior answer, you have not defined $f(0).$ Let us define $f(0)=0.$ For $x\ne 0$ we have $$0<f(x)=\frac {1}{\exp {(1/x^2)}}<\frac {1}{1+1/x^2}=\frac {x^2}{x^2+1}<x^2.$$ So $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=0=f(0).$

We can also show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\in \{0\}\cup \Bbb N$ by induction on $n,$ where $f^{(0)}=f,$ and $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative of $f$ when $n>0:$

We have already done the case $n=0.$

For any $n\ge 0$ we have (by induction on $n$) $ f^{(n)}(x)=f(x)P_n(1/x)$ when $x\ne 0,$ where $P_n$ is a polynomial.

So suppose $f^{(n)}(0)=0.$ Then when $x\ne 0$ we have $$\frac {f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(0)}{x-0}=f(x)(1/x)P_n(1/x).$$ Let deg $(P_n)=D_n.$  For $x\ne 0$ we have $1/f(x)=\exp (1/x^2)>\dfrac {(1/x^2)^{1+D_n}}{(1+D_n)!}.$ So we have $$|f(x)(1/x)P_n(1/x)|\le (1+D_n)!\cdot |x^{1+D_n}| \cdot |x^{D_n}P_n(1/x)|.$$

Now $x^{D_n}P_n(1/x)$ is a polynomial in $x$. So $f^{(n+1)}(0)=0.$

Comment: Nice proof (+1)

Answer (score 0):

A very useful fact that would help you in this situation is that for a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where for all $x\neq 0$, we have that $f'(x)$ exists, if $$\lim_{x\to 0} f’(x) = L\in\mathbb{R}$$ exists, then $f'(0)$ exists and $f’(0)=L$.

Comment: Not true. Consider $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: It was a typo, now it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the question can lead to a circular argument.

You don't define $f(0)$, so it is tempting to extend it by setting $f(0)=0$ (several answerers did it). But this choice is made to ensure that $f$ is continuous at $0$, so that... $f$ is continuous at $0$.

A better question is "evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}e^{-1/x^2}$". You can easily establish this for example by squeezing in $[0,x]$.