# Establish Smoothness of Green's functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

suppose $R>0$ and $ G(\bar{z};\bar{x})= \frac{1}{4\pi}\log{ \frac{\left \| \bar{x} - \bar{z}\right \|^2}{\left \| \bar{x}- \frac{R^2}{\left \| \bar{z}\right \|^2}\bar{z}\right \|^2}}-\frac{1}{4\pi}\log{\frac{\left \| \bar{z}\right \|^2}{R^2}} $  if $\bar{z} \neq \bar{0}$ and $G(\bar{0};\bar{x}) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\log{ \left \| \bar{x}\right \|^2}-\frac{1}{4\pi}\log{R^2} $ is Green's function for the disk with radius $R$ centered in the origin. How can $C^{\infty}$- smoothness be established for $\bar{x}\neq\bar{z}$ and $\bar{x}\neq \frac{R^2}{\left \| \bar{z}\right \|^2}\bar{z}$ in not too difficult a manner? Of course, my only concern is regions containing points of the form $(\bar{0};\bar{x})$.

Comment: $\|x\|^2 = x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$. Where is the problem?

Comment: Switching between the two different definitions $\bar{z}=0$ and $\bar{z}\neq 0$. I'll have another think about it.

Comment: OK, I was reading too fast. Idea: calculate the partial derivatives and prove continuity in the problematic points. For passing from $C^1$ to $C^2$,... maybe a trick similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510275/differentiability-of-fx-exp-1-x2-f0-0 will work.

Comment: Got it, with a change of variables such as $(\bar{z};\bar{x})=(\rho \cos{\gamma},\rho \sin{\gamma};r \cos{\theta},r \sin{\theta})$ one can unify both definitions and smoothness follows in a straightforward way.